# subclass mac OS colorpickers to add a button

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, color-picker

I have a color well, that when clicked brings up the Mac OS X `NSColorPanel`. I have all the default color pickers enabled. However, there are three flavors of each color picker I need. Two are already provided by the show Alpha and don't show Alpha options. I need a third, which I was hoping to just add a toggle button, that would stand for 0 alpha and full (1) alpha.

From what I'm seeing though, you have to create a totally new nib file. Is there a way to use the default colorpickers as a template for this? and then I could just subclass their implementation to look at this toggle button?

I'm looking at http://filibeto.org/unix/macos/lib/dev/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/DrawColor.pdf for information on subclassing the `NSColorPicker`s and using the MyColorPicker.xcodeproj example from Apple trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSColorPicker's [accessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColorPanel/setAccessoryView%3a) to add additional controls.